# Uploading an exclusion list of only email addresses

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, exclusion-script

I have a list of only emails that i would like to exclude from a single send. Issue:

Since these emails may or may not be in our system, i do not have a unique id/subscriber key for them. Since it is not best practice to relate email to subscriberkey, do I need to generate a unique ID for each? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> If your Email Studio account has subscriber key enabled, the system
> excludes using the subscriber key value. If your account does not have
> subscriber key enabled, the system excludes using email address.

This means that if you have been using subscriber keys, then you have to use the same keys for the exclusion list as the ones you use for your sends, otherwise it won’t work.

Example:

```
Subscriber key in send: 1234
Email address in send: test@email.com
```

The only way to exclude email `test@email.com` is to put the subscriber key 1234 in the exclusion list.

So to make it work, you first need to find the subscriber keys used for the email address you want to exclude.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_exclusion_list.htm&language=en_US&type=5

Comment: Thanks for this info. Could i use an exclusion script that just looks at the email field?

Comment: Yes, that would work

Comment: Ok in that scenario, would you advise to set up a DE with UniqueID, Email. UniqueID relates to subscriberkey and then add the exclusion script: (ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Exclusion_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME_1", "EMAIL_ADDR_FIELD_NAME", EMAILADDR)) > 0)

Comment: You don’t need a unique key in that DE as you won’t be using it for sending, just the email column is fine

Comment: So this can be a non sendable DE?

Comment: Yes. Make sure to test it before doing the actual send out!